# How to find flights with a specific layover?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, flight-search-engines

I live in ATL and would like to find flights that have a layover in SLC (where we can leave kids with grandparents). Flexible on dates and potential destinations.

Although would also be nice to be able to specific destination/duration/etc... example: ATL - SLC - HNL in December. Are there any search engines out there that provide this?

Comment: Are you looking for a multi-city itinerary, where you have a stop-over of a day or more in the middle?  Or are you envisioning a situation where your kids fly ATL–SLC and you fly ATL–SLC–somewhere else, with the first leg of the flight being the same one your kids are on?

Comment: Do you mean layover or just a connection?  It's an important difference in how you book.

Answer (score 7):

You want to pick the "Multi City" option on most flight search engines.

I just checked on [SkyScanners](https://www.skyscanner.net/) multicity option for flights from ATL to SLC on 1st Dec and then from SLC to HNL on 2nd Dec, returning from HNL on the 30th Dec and got lots of results.

Comment: This MultiCity option is not really a layover as it shows you two different flights. What I need(ed) is/was a single flight with a layover in a very specific city.

Answer (score 3):

[**Skiplagged**](https://skiplagged.com/) allows you to search based on layover stop, especially if your destination is flexible.

Note: Airlines don't especially like the basic idea behind the site, of people buying connections they don't intend to use, to get lower overall fares, because it messes up their financial models based on route competition, even though they wind up selling more tickets than the actual work they'll have to do to support customer travel.  Recognize that failing to travel on any leg can lead to e.g. cancellation of the rest of the legs on that reservation.

Answer (score 3):

Since you know you want to go to SLC, why not:

1. Look for reasonably priced flights from ATL to ALC. Note which airlines they are with.
2. Look for flights to wherever you want to go from SLC, and specifically look for flights with those airlines
3. Then look at flights to your preferred destinations with those airlines. Chances are that one with a layover in SLC will be offered.

This also gives you the option of taking a longer pause in SLC.